# DataGridView.SelectAll() except for the last row?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is there a way to select everything in a datagridview all but the last row? Other than manually selecting the rows. If I use `DataGridView.SelectAll();` it selects everything in my datagridview including the empty line at the bottom which I don't want to include.

Comment: Call `SelectAll` and deselect the last one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just manually un-select the last row after you call `SelectAll`:

```
dataGridView.SelectAll();

if (dataGridView.RowCount > 0)
{
    var lastRow = dataGridView.Rows[dataGridView.RowCount - 1];
    lastRow.Selected = false;
}
```